# How do you call it when you remove the top n% and the bottom n% of a dataset?

Tags: terminology, data-analysis

I am currently writing about a dataset of collected handwritings. I want to show some characteristics of the dataset. For example I think it is interesting to show how long it took users to create the dataset.

So I extract for each recording the time and thus get a list of non-negative real numbers. As a few instances have values > 30,000 and some < 5, but most instances are in [30, 60], I want to cut off those outliers and visualize only the rest in a plot.

So I remove the top 0.5% and the bottom 0.5% before visualizing it (where the x-axis is the time $t$ and the y-axis is the number of recordings with recording time lower than $t$).

Is there a name for removing the lower 0.5% and the top 0.5% of all datasets? (where 0.5% refers to the total number of datasets, not to the values)

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but might be relevant to you: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16198/what-do-you-call-an-average-that-does-not-include-outliers

Comment: It is sometimes called removing *outliers* (a technical term) or embarrassments (not a technical term).

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Why embarrassments?

Comment: Experimental data that one would prefer not to display.

Comment: @AndréNicolas That sounds as if you want to say that I would manipulate data that does not fit to a hypothesis. This is definitely not the case. I will mention those outliers in the text and write down at least the maximum. The only reason why I want to remove them before plotting is that the plot would otherwise be very hard to read.

Comment: The remark had nothing to do with you. But I have certainly seen experimental data that had results that people wanted to remove. If this is done in a consistent announced-ahead-of-time way, it is standard and unexceptionable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I have done this in the past,
this was called "trimming"
(not my term).

I used this to make graphics more visible,
and I typically trimmed
the top and bottom 5% of values,
not 5% of number of points.

More specifically,
if the values ranged from
0 to 100,
I removed all the points
with values
that were > 95
or < 5,
and then rescaled the display
so the remaining points
were displayed from the
min to the max
(usually 0 to 255).

I found that this made
details in the data much easier to see.

Another method is to
generate a histogram of the values
and adjust the displayed values
such that the modified display
has a uniform histogram.
This essentially uses
the inverse distribution.

Comment: Some of those values are extremely much higher than 99% of the "normal" data (the maximum is about 10,000 times higher than the maximum of the remaining 99%). So I really want to remove the top 0.5% of the data. The minimum is not that extreme (as the values are not so high and non-negative). The only reason why I remove the bottom 0.5% is due to symmetry.

Comment: Do it whichever way you want, whether you want to trim the top 5% of the points or the points with 5% of the values. I suggest that you try both and see which works best for you.

Comment: I've just talked with a friend about it. He suggested using another plot type. It turns out that this works much better and I can even include the outliers :-)

Comment: Don't keep us in suspense - what did he suggest?

Comment: Simply a histogram. You can see a neat visualization of my data here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/195034/5645